# No route matches [POST] "/student_tests/upload.1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

But I wanted it to match [POST] "/student_tests/1/upload"

IN The routes.rb  i have  added

```
resources :student_tests do
    member do
      post 'upload'
    end
end
```

In the students_test_controller i have added

```
def upload
    render :upload
end
```

In the index page of student_test

```
<%= link_to "| Upload Scaled Scores", upload_student_test_path(test), method: :edit%>
```

where test is an object of student_test

By using Rack routes

```
upload_student_test POST  /student_tests/:id/upload(.:format)   student_tests#upload
```

What mistake have i made that its searching for "/student_tests/upload.1" i want it to look for  "/student_tests/1/upload" (here 1 is the id of student test)

Comment: can you paste the link_to code you are using to generate the hyper reference?

Answer (score 1):

You've created an 'POST' member action in your route but you've linked to it in wrong way:

```
<%= link_to "| Upload Scaled Scores", upload_student_test_path(test), method: :edit%>
```

which should actually be like:

```
<%= link_to "| Upload Scaled Scores", upload_student_test_path(test), method: :post %>
```

However, this may not be conventional way of rails routing. If you just want to render a views there, a `GET` method will be most appropriate. When you upload file(s), you can use the `POST` method as you tried here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you used your route could be changed as follows:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

I don't understand the reason why you want the ID before the controller's action. You can change the routes format and access the ID accordingly.

The way you have framed the question could have been better as I found hard to understand your question. Answering here with what I understand.